# examine command in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

> A number can also be prepended to the format of the examine command
>   to examine multiple units at the target address.

*source: hacking the art of exploration*

```
(gdb) x/2x $eip
0x8048384 <main+16>:   0x00fc45c7 0x83000000

(gdb) x/x $eip
0x8048384 <main+16>:   0x00fc45c7
```

I know that the second examine command returns the memory address that eip is currently locating. What about the first one which returns two memory address?

Comment: `$eip` can be seen as a pointer variable. So in C terms, `x/x $eip` prints `$eip[0]` and `x/2x $eip` prints `$eip[0]` and `$eip[1]`.

Comment: OK, what does they indicate?

Comment: Then let me ask you this: Do you know what `EIP` is and what it's used for? What do you think that `$eip` is pointing at?

Comment: Yes, EIP is a register inside the CPU, it is used to hold the memory address of instructions in our program which is currently executing. $eip is pointing to the address in the .text section of our program.

Comment: My question is, there is only 1 $eip, so why it shows two memory address?

Comment: There you have it then. `$eip` is pointing to the current instruction in the code. Whatever that instruction is I don't know. You have to decode the value `0x00fc45c7` yourself (and note that it could be *multiple* instructions since some x86 instructions are only a single byte).

Comment: If you had e.g. `int *my_array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));` and then in the debugger did `x/2x my_array`, what would you expect to see? The two first elements of the array I hope. It's the same here, the debugger treats `$eip` as a pointer to the first element of an array of 32-bit integer elements.

Comment: Thanks, I got you man. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189648/discussion-between-henok-tesfaye-and-some-programmer-dude).

Answer (score 2):

The [examine command of gdb](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC56) has the following syntax:

```
x/[n][f][u]
```

where **n**, **f** and **u** are optional and **n** is the length, **f** the format and **u** the unit size.

Possible formats are:

- s (null terminated string)
- i (machine code instruction)
- x (hexadecimal value)

If no unit size can be one of the following values:

- b (bytes)
- h (2 bytes)
- w (4 bytes)
- g (8 bytes)

where **w** is the default.

Therefore `x/2x` prints 2 hexadecimal values with a size of 4 bytes from your code segment.